# Get current ZoomControlStyle being used by Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to get the current style being used by the map zoom control?

e.g. google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.**SMALL**, or google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.**LARGE**

You can specifiy the start style in mapOptions but the map changes the style to small if the web browser is resized too small, or the map is being viewed on a touch device.

I show custom labels next to the zoom control on [www.topomap.co.nz](http://www.topomap.co.nz) and would like to hide the labels if the control style becomes SMALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a hack that is likely to need revising in future Google Maps API releases as the graphics get tweaked by Google:

```
function isFullGoogleZoomControl() {
    return $("#map .gmnoprint img[src$='mapcontrols3d7.png']").length > 0;
}
```

Note: Requires jQuery for the selector.

**Update to include support for IE10 with touch screen:**

```
function isFullGoogleZoomControl() {
    return $("#map .gmnoprint img[src$='mapcontrols3d7.png']").length > 1;
}
```

Comment: with google.maps.visualRefresh set to true it changes a litte:

return $("#map .gmnoprint img[src$='mapcnt3.png']").length > 2;

Answer (score 0):

The zoom control changes automatically at the following sizes,  perhaps you could attach an event listener to the onsize method, and monitor the size of you canvas and adapt once the resolution has changed.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

The sizes are:

Greater than 400x350px = large zoom

Less than 400x350px = small zoom (the control adjusts if either extent is less than this amount)

Comment: Thanks for the great tip javram. I'm still hoping to find a solution where I can get this directly off the maps api in some way as it will future proof the code for me. Your method is great for sizing of the map, but still needs extra code for iPads etc. which use the small version all the time. Then there's probably 101 devices that the same thing will happen for across multiple OS's. So would be best to get this state directly from the horses mouth so to speak. Even if it's an undocumented hack tied to a specific version of the api such as 3.7, 3.8 etc.